# Brackets in python rgex

Tags: python, regex

Here's a strip of my code:

```
import re

prog2 = re.compile(r'\[\w\]')
activity = "[CS150]"
if prog2.match(activity): 
    print 'matched'
else:
    print 'unmatched'
```

I don't know why it prints unmatched, because I stated the pattern well I think and gave a right input.

Answer (score 1):

You need to match more than one character:

```
prog2 = re.compile(r'\[\w+\]')
```

Note the `+` quantifier. Without it, the `\w` character class will match just *one* character, with it, the pattern matches *at least* one character.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> prog2 = re.compile(r'\[\w+\]')
>>> activity = "[CS150]"
>>> prog2.match(activity)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x106b2f6b0>
```

Comment: You beat me to this one, but that war ain't over yet! :)

Comment: @user3226156: No, `\w` does *not* include spaces. `\w` only includes letters, digits and underscores. You can match `[\w ]+` to match both word characters and spaces.

Comment: Yeah I just realized it. But how can I add a space to \w, I don't care what the position of space will be.

Comment: @user3226156: I just showed you; the whole pattern would be `r'\[[\w ]+\]'`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an * at the end of your regexp. Otherwise it matches a single  character.

Answer (score 0):

This below gives the expected result

```
import re
prog2 = re.compile(r'\[\w+\]')
activity = "[CS150]"
if prog2.match(activity): 
    print ('matched')
else:
    print ('unmatched')

>>matched
```

Hope that was helpful !